# How to change the shape of a button in visual c++?

Tags: visual-c++

Is there an easy way to change the shape of a button in a form?

Answer (score 0):

There  could be other ways, but if you are not using WPF, you can use Images for buttons.

If you are using WPF, there are lots of options you can explore.

Comment: I am not using WPF. And I want to change the shape which can't be done using an image.Can you tell me how to use WPF for this?

Comment: WPF is little bit complex and it's a new Technology altogether. If you are building professionals applications, I suggest you consider learning it. It's the next Generation Tech for developing Windows Form Apps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gunner. I need this urgent to complete an assignment. If can please tell me a short method.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit old, but may point the way, look at ownerdraw properties and styles and messages. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364048(v=vs.80).aspx

As an aside why would you want to change the shape of the button. Bear in mind your users, they more than likely don't like change.

Comment: Thanks Sasquiha. This one I got as an assignment. And I was looking for a short way to achieve this since I am running out of time. Anyway I will try this.

Comment: How much time do you have, I would expect you to have quite a few problems with C++ and windows programming itself before even getting to drawing buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to Ownerdraw buttons. The following links shall help you.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/buttons/roundbuttons.aspx

[how to create a round/circular button in win32 API using visual c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1722750/102062)