# Circular button using BM_SETIMAGE and SetWindowRgn

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

**I'm attempting to create a circular push button. Here's my process so far:**

Create BS_BITMAP style button:

```
hButton = CreateWindow(L"button",L"Label",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|BS_BITMAP,
               122,363,65,65,hWnd,(HMENU)BUTTON_ID,NULL,NULL);
```

Load bitmap with LoadImage. The bitmap is a square, but I only want to display the circle in the center (more on this later):

```
buttonImage = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(hInstance,L"button.bmp",IMAGE_BITMAP,65,65, 
               LR_LOADFROMFILE|LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
```

Set the button's image:

```
SendMessage(hButton,BM_SETIMAGE,IMAGE_BITMAP,(LPARAM)buttonImage);
```

In order to display just the circle, I use the following:

```
hButtonRgn = CreateEllipticRgn(0,0,65,65);
SetWindowRgn(hButton,hButtonRgn,TRUE);
```

Note that I define hButtonRgn globally and don't use it again, as the MSDN documentation for SetWindowRgn states that "the system owns the region specified by the region handle hRgn".

**Here's the problem:**

The button initially appears as only a circle. On being clicked and held, though, the full square bitmap appears, with white space surrounding the circle. However, upon release, only the circle appears again.

**Here's my attempted solution:**

As soon as the button is clicked, repaint the main window around the button. Within the main window's WndProc, then, I do the following:

```
case WM_PARENTNOTIFY:
    if ((int)wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();
        // paint the background surrounding the button in another function
        pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
```

However, this has no discernible effect. The button appears circular after releasing the mouse, but appears as a square when the mouse is being held down.

Any ideas on where I've gone wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create a round/circular button in win32 API using visual c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722750/how-to-create-a-round-circular-button-in-win32-api-using-visual-c)

Comment: You probably want to use an owner-drawn button rather than a bitmap button.  Petzold has an ellipse example in _Programming Windows_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your redraw routine is incorrect. `BeginPaint()` should only be used in response to a `WM_PAINT` message - it tells you that something is dirty and needs repainting. What you want to do is trigger that mechanism, and the way you do that is to use `InvalidateRect()` to mark the appropriate area of the parent window for redraw.

Even if this does improve things for you I think you'll end up with flickering which will probably be unacceptable. Another mechanism you could investigate is making the button owner draw, because then you can just draw it as a circle (and invalidate the parent window) in the same step.