# How to make a circular button in Winforms?

Tags: windows, winforms, button, visual-c++

I have a form in visual C++.
I have a button .How to make it circular.
Do I have to code it?
Even in radio button option its not possible to change its radius and get rid of the dot .
Please help

Comment: there is similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432175/circular-button-using-bm-setimage-and-setwindowrgn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create custom button using circular picture. [Search for this](https://www.google.ru/webhp?#q=visual%20studio%20picture%20button) to know how to do it.